# Problems in defining limits fmincon using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

this is my question:

I have six parametres that I'll vary in fmincon toolbox of MATLAB, and these are the restrictions:

```
variables=[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6]

x1<=x2
x3<=x4
x5<=x6
```

So, I defined the A matrix for fmincon like this:

```
A=[1 -1 0  0 0  0;   0  0 1 -1 0  0;    0  0 0  0 1 -1];
```

and vector b:

```
b=[0;0;0];
```

And the problem is that fmincon doesn't respect the conditions (if they are well defined), I mean por the first iteration, the parameters were:

```
ddx=[1 1 1 1 1 1];
```

And for the second iteration the variation was:

```
ddx=[2 1 1 1 1 1];
```

As you can see, there's a mistake with respect the definition in the boundaries, because x1=2 and x2=1; which is not right.

I hope you can give me some ideas.

This is an example:

```
function Example
clc
global xo
lbr=[2,2,300,300,3,3];
upr=[8,8,2000,2000,6,6];
xo =[3,4,400,500,4,5];

Aeq=[];
beq=[];

% Matríz de condiciones
Ain=[1 -1 0 0 0 0;0 0 1 -1 0 0;0 0 0 0 1 -1];
bin=[0;0;0];

lb=lbr./xo;
ub=upr./xo;

xo_n=ones(1,size(upr,2));

options1 = optimset('Display','iter',...
    'Algorithm','sqp','PlotFcns',@optimplotfval,...
    'MaxIter',400,'MaxFunEvals',1000,'DiffMinChange',1);

[ddx, FOval] = fmincon(@MyfunSSI,xo_n,Ain,bin,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,[],options1);




end

function [FO]=MyfunSSI(ddx)
global xo

ddx

x1=xo(1)*ddx(1);
x2=xo(2)*ddx(2);
x3=xo(3)*ddx(3);
x4=xo(4)*ddx(4);
x5=xo(5)*ddx(5);
x6=xo(6)*ddx(6);

% These are the conditions:
x1<=x2
x3<=x4
x5<=x6

FO=1;

end
```

As you can see, the restrictions are not respected.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? For instance, what is your exact call to fmincon?

Comment: There it go, @JandeGier, I hope you can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After the function fmincon  terminates, it should either satisfy the constraints, or indicated that it cannot find a feasible solution.

That during the optimization iterations constraints are violated, can be advantageous for certain problems, and hence this is supported by some of the algorithms (at least the Active Set algorithm) in fmincon. If you dont like this behavior, use Interior Point. For more details, see [fmincon algorithms](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/optim/ug/choosing-a-solver.html#bsbwxm7) and [violating constraints](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/optim/ug/writing-constraints.html#br9p_ry).

---

**edit** The thing that is going wrong is your objective function `MyfunSSI`. It just returns 1, and hence there is nothing to minimize. In addition, you are just putting the constraint statements, without processing them in any way. The constraints are dealt with by the `A` and `b` matrix, so forget about these. But the main thing is: change the function a proper objective function that uses the input `ddx` to come up with an output value `FO`.

And by the way, using `sqp` in this way means that the optimizer will use finite differences and hence evaluate the objective function *near* feasible and hence possibly *infeasible* points.

Comment: That isn't the problem, in the example FO=1 because I define it like that, in my real problem I have another objective function. This problem actually is about the parameters that don't respect the initial conditions, like in the third iteration x1>x2, and that is wrong.